# Testing Exchange Web Services (EWS)

Tags: .net, azure, integration-testing, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am implementing a .NET application that uses Exchange Web Services (EWS) to process e-mails. That all works nice and dandy. But when it comes to acceptance and integration testing on different instances, this gets tricky because of the EWS dependency. I also use virtualization with Vagrant.

**What is a good and robust way of resolving this dependency in a testing environment across many instances (for instance, to enable testing on feature branches)?** Is it easy to have an Exchange server with EWS enabled on a virtual box? How about cloud integration where you would have an exchange instance with many test mail addresses (like on Azure)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get all of your pain points on this, but one thing that comes to mind is getting a subscription to Exchange Online (AKA O365) and assigning different mailboxes to different environments.  E.g. MBDEV001-025 to development, MBQA001-025 to QA, MBSUP001-025 to support, etc.  Internally we maintain a decent Exchange 2010 environment in house, but you'll need at least 2 servers (VMs OK) and an MSDN license that will allow you to download and install Exchange to run for tests.  That will give you the most flexibility.  You probably would want both because any Exchange app nowadays would be expected to support both on-prem and O365 Exchange.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The team consists of a few people with multiple PCs each who run Vagrant instances at will. I am looking more for a dynamic approach. Creating email addresses is not a big deal but assigning them dynamically is what I am after. Hence the idea of running an Exchange server on the boxes.